# Disable Istio default retry strategy (at least on POST requests)

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I have an application (microservices-based) running on kubernets with Istio 1.7.4

The microservices has its own mechanisms of transaction compensation on integration failures.

But Istio is retrying requests, when some integrations has 503 status code responses. I need to disabled it (at least on POST, which is non-idenpontent).

And let the application take care of it.

But I've tried so many ways without success. Can someone help me?

Comment: can yo provide information of what have you tried?

Comment: also can you provide your most important configs and request example. Need to start from investigating at least something. Hard to guess here.

Comment: I've tried this: https://discuss.istio.io/t/disable-globally-the-default-retry-policy/9126
And another variations of this policy, changing the atrributes (retry_on conditions and retriable_status_codes)

I also read that Istio had a bug on validating this policy, making impossible to change the atrribute attempts to zero. Look:

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14900
https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13851

Comment: It looks like the bug is still there on Istio 1.7.4

Comment: But I could skip this default policy by change the status code response on application level. I'm not proud of it, but it's the only solution I've found there.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Documentation**

- From [Istio Retries documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#retries): Default `retry` is hardcoded and it's value equal to 2.

> The interval between retries (25ms+) is variable and determined
> automatically by Istio, preventing the called service from being
> overwhelmed with requests. **The default retry** behavior for HTTP
> requests **is to retry twice** before returning the error.

Btw, it was initially 10, but decreased to 2 in [Enable retries for specific status codes and reduce num retries to 2](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/12188/commits/cc7f5bc4f4bc0bc7806e8ad3ec145d4968f42e02) commit.

- workaround is to use virtual services

> **you can adjust your retry settings on a per-service basis in virtual
> services** without having to touch your service code. You can also
> further refine your retry behavior by adding per-retry timeouts,
> specifying the amount of time you want to wait for each retry attempt
> to successfully connect to the service.

---

**Examples**

1. The following example configures a maximum of 3 retries to connect to this service subset after an initial call failure, each with a 2 second timeout.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ratings
spec:
  hosts:
  - ratings
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings
        subset: v1
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 2s
```

2. **Your case. Disabling retries.** Taken from [Disable globally the default retry policy](https://discuss.istio.io/t/disable-globally-the-default-retry-policy/9126):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: no-retries-for-one-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - one-service.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - retries:
      attempts: 0
    route:
      - destination:
          host: one-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I've tried this solution. And another variations of this policy, changing the attributes (retry_on conditions and retriable_status_codes). 

I also read that Istio had a bug on validating this policy, making impossible to change the attribute attempts to zero. 

Take a look here: [link](http://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14900) and [link](http://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13851)

Comment: It looks like the bug is still there on Istio 1.7.4. But I could skip this default policy by change the status code response on application level. I'm not proud of it, but it's the only solution I've found there.

Comment: we are facing the same bug with version 1.11.2 as well. The Virtual service retry attempt value of 0 is not getting to the proxy config and which is still using the default value 2